# React Initializing and synchronizing state with backend

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, data-synchronization

I wonder what is the best way/pattern to initialize state and keep it synced with the server. I've read and tried a lot for the last couple of days but haven't found anything that solves my question.

The example is really simple. There is a state - it's a number in the example for the sake of simplicity, although in real life it would be an object - that I need to retrieve from the server. Once retrieved, I want it to be synchronized with the server. The getValueFromServer is a mock that returns a random value after waiting a random amount of time in a setTimeout.

So, to initialize my state I use a useEffect on an empty array as a dependency, and to keep it synched I use a useEffect with the state as a dependency.

The problem is that it is trying to save an undefined value. The log is as follows.

1 -> Initializing for first time

2 -> API call to save in server value:  undefined

3 -> API call to save in server value:  6.026930847574949

What I get:

1: Runs on mounting as expected.

2: This one I didn't expect. I guess it is triggered because of the "useState".

3: Runs once we get the response from the server. Kind of obvious but a pain in the ass, because why on earth would I want to save this.

What would the best approach be here? Using something like a "isInitialized" flag in the useEffect with dependency feels kind of hacked and not professional.

Code below and you can find it working here too: https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-rgb-uce9f

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { getValueFromServer } from "./api";

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function initialize() {
      console.log("Initializing for first time");
      let serverValue = await getValueFromServer();
      setValue(serverValue);
    }
    initialize();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("API call to save in server value: ", value);
  }, [value]);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setValue(value + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Value: {value}</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Add 1 to value</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would the best approach be here? Using something like a
>   "isInitialized" flag in the useEffect with dependency feels kind of
>   hacked and not professional.

You can either use a flag or initialize object with default value in `useState`

```js
const { Fragment, useState, useEffect } = React;

const getValueFromServer = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve(Math.random())), 1000)

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    let isUnmounted = false;
  
    getValueFromServer().then(serverValue => {
      console.log("Initializing for first time");
      if(isUnmounted) {
        return;
      }
      setValue(serverValue);
      setLoading(false);
    })
    
    return () => {
      isUnmounted = true;
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!value) {
      return () => {}
    }
  
    console.log("API call to save in server value: ", value);
    setTimeout(() => setLoading(false), 50);
  }, [value]);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    setValue(value + 1);
  };

  return <div className="App">
    {isLoading ? <Fragment>
      <span>Loading...</span>
    </Fragment> : <Fragment>
      <h1>Value: {value}</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Add 1 to value</button>
    </Fragment>}
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/7.10.1/polyfill.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Hi! Many thanks. Pretty concise answer. I see that using flags is unavoidable. I would have to use another flag to avoid calling the server to store the value that I just retrieved the first time. Thank you, very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

your app does other stuff while it's busy `await`ing something to happen in your first `useEffect` hook function.  "other stuff" in this case is "executing your second `useEffect` hook function".  `serverValue`, and therefore `value`, is not defined at this point, so your `console.log` prints `undefined`.  once your `await` promise resolves to a value and `setValue` gets called, your second `useEffect` hook function's dependencies change causing your function to be run a second time (and printing out the value you expect).

if you have to have two `useEffect` hooks, then just bail out of the second one when `value` is undefined:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if (value === undefined) {
      return;
    }

    console.log('value is:', value);
  }, [ value ]);
```

Comment: I would have left this as a comment, or voted to close the question as a dupe, but I kinda surprisingly couldn't find an existing answered SO question talking about multiple `useEffect` hooks.  maybe someone else will have better luck?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I knew that it was doing stuff while awaiting. What I am really interested is in your last line, it seems that value checking or flagging is unavoidable. Thanks!